# pass value in autocomplete ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, autocomplete

I'm trying to use two autocompletes in a page, connected by each other. I'm trying to pass a variable from one autocomplete to another. I´ll leave you the code to see if someone could help me.

JS:
    $(function(){

```
        $('#buscador').autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            source: "home/get_cliente",

            focus: function(event,ui){
                $('#buscador').val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            },
            select: function(event, ui){
                id_cliente = ui.item.value;
                $('#id_cliente').val(id_cliente);
                return false;  

                    $('#vehiculo').autocomplete({
                    minLength: 1,
                    source: "home/get_carro?id_cliente="+id_cliente,
```

this line up here is the one I´m not sure about.

```
                    focus: function(event,ui){
                        $('#vehiculo').val(ui.item.label);
                        return false;
                    }
                }); //Fin autocomplete vehiculo
            }
        }); //Fin autocomplete buscador
    });
```

Comment: I don´t know how to pass the value id_cliente from the first autocomplete to the second autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
     $(function(){
        // Declare global var
        var id_cliente = "";
        $('#buscador').autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            source: "home/get_cliente",

            focus: function(event,ui){
                $('#buscador').val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            },
            select: function(event, ui){
                id_cliente = ui.item.value;
                $('#id_cliente').val(id_cliente);
                return false;  

                    $('#vehiculo').autocomplete({
                    minLength: 1,
                    source: "home/get_carro?id_cliente="+id_cliente, 
                    focus: function(event,ui){
                        $('#vehiculo').val(ui.item.label);
                        return false;
                    }
                }); //Fin autocomplete vehiculo
            }
        }); //Fin autocomplete buscador
    });
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering. I´m not very good explaining myself, my problem is that I´m not sure if this line:(source: "home/get_carro?id_cliente="+id_cliente) is correct

Comment: that line of code is correct what is the problem your are facing with the code?